# Cannot manage .sdf file in VS 2010 Ultimate SP1

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I keep getting this error whenever I try to open a local DB `.sdf` file in VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate

> Data provider required to connect to local data file could not be found.The file will be added to project but the typed dataset associated with the file will not be generated.

I have the VS 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 already installed.

Basically I had VS 2010 Express installed and that worked just fine, I have since uninstalled it and installed VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate.

[image]

How can I fix this annoying error?

Comment: Did you reinstall the SQL CE tools since installing VS Ultimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the SQL Server Compact 4.0 Tools for VS 2010 SP1 as well, I have a direct link here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html